# Conditional Formatting of rows within a block of data

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I want to be able to apply conditional formatting quickly to rows in a series of tables in Excel (using Excel 2007 currently) to pick out the maximum and minimum value in each row. It's easy enough to do it a row at a time: simply select the row, Click on Conditional Formatting, pick Top/Bottom rules, pick Top 10 items, change the `10` to a `1` - and then repeat the process for the Bottom 1 item.  Slow.

But if I try to copy & paste-special formatting to remaining rows in what might be a long table, then it picks out the top and bottom for the whole block - not what's wanted.

As it happens, I think I can figure out a way to do it with a VBA macro (so you'd select the block and run the macro via keyboard accelerator) but I prefer not to expose team members to VBA for all sorts of reasons.  So ideally I'm looking for a "formula" that I can put in the "new rule" dialogue. I figure the formula (if it can be devised) would, for each cell to which it applies, test its value against the MAX (MIN for a second rule) of all values in the current row - where rows are as wide as they happen to be for that block of data.

I've been boggling at combinations of INDEX(), INDIRECT(), ROW(), and I keep thinking I've almost got it, only to find I'm stumped again.

Any ideas, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember when writing conditional formatting on a block of data, that you are actually writing the formula *exactly as shown in the formula bar* for the top left cell of a data block. Every other cell is the same formula *as if you'd copied and pasted that formula down/to the right as needed*. So that means that you look at absolute references ($'s), and relative references (no $'s).

For example:

In a datablock B2:D10, we want the max & min of each row highlighted. If we were going to write this formula for only B2, we'd say [remember, the formula is to be written so that it either says TRUE, meaning the conditional format applies, or anything else, and then the format does not apply]:

```
=OR(B2=MIN(B2:D2),B2=MAX(B2:D2))
```

If B2 is equal to either the min or max of that row, the rule will resolve as TRUE, and the formatting will apply. To extrapolate that for the other cells, now look at what you want to 'stay the same', and what you want to 'change', as you copy this formula down and to the right:

```
=OR(B2=MIN($B2:$D2),B2=MAX($B2:$D2))
```

In the above, we always want the 'B2=M...' to change in the row and column - because that will apply the rule individually to each new cell. We also want '$B' to stay the same, because the columns you are comparing with dont change [you are always comparing with column B - D]. We do however want the row of the checked ranges to change, as the row changes as you drag down.

Comment: (I find I can't post my full reply due to character-count limit!)
Succinct and elegant;  thank you.  However, I also want to extend this procedure to cope with rows in a selected block of any number of columns.

Comment: I often need to visualise values in columns (rather than rows, as in this case), and I've learned the keyboard accelerators Control+Shift+UpArrow (which selects the entire column if applied when the bottom cell is selected) followed by Alt+H, L, D, _arrow-key_ (to apply data bars to the values in the column).  With the help of a bit of macro recording I can see that it should be possible to do this sort of magic with a VBA macro, which could be linked to a keyboard accelerator, which would speed things up hugely.

Comment: However, I do try to avoid sharing VBA with colleagues where possible (many painful experiences!) so I'd puzzled over the possibility of a formula-based approach.  The idea was that my colleague would store the formula somewhere, and then copy & paste it into the CF formula box after selecting a block of rows for treatment.  Then, of course, the geek in me wants to know the solution just for the fun of it!

Comment: @PhilipHerlihy I don't really follow what you're getting at here... Do you have a question? Looks like this might be different enough from what you've originally asked to warrant a new one.

Comment: It's clear I didn't put my original question clearly - although I did include the words _"all values in the current row - where rows are as wide as they happen to be for that block of data."_  and I've also re-stated this goal in the first of my comments above.  I'm sorry if I've been rather opaque in setting out the puzzle.

Comment: @PhilipHerlihy Then just eliminate the column letters altogether. As long as there is only ever a single datablock, this will look all the way to the end of the sheet: "=OR(A2=MIN(2:2),A2=MAX(2:2))" Apply it to the whole sheet, or at least from A1-> to the bottom right of your data.

Comment: That is simply brilliant.  It works, of course.  I had no idea you could specify a range without column letters - where can I look this up to understand it better?

I owe you a pint!

Comment: @PhilipHerlihy Glad I could help; there's not much more to be said on the matter. "A:A" means all of column A; "1:1" means all of row one. In many cases you can refer to a whole row or column without significantly affecting performance (because Excel intuitively knows to stop attempting to pull data from cells outside of the used range of a sheet), but sometimes it does call problems. For simplicity in small workbooks, I generally prefer to refer to whole columns (for vlookup etc.), as it is a little 'cleaner' and better 'future proofed'.

Comment: Thank you.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I looked this up - there it is in Help (never previously noticed).  I looked for what else I didn't know, and I came across Tables and Structured References.  As the **n:n** reference to a row must also include rows from any other block of data on the same worksheet row (e.g. where two "blocks" are separated by a blank column, I wondered if Tables and Structured References might be better.  Nope!  I did find that the **INDIRECT()** function stopped Excel throwing errors, but I couldn't get this to work:
**=INDIRECT("Table1[[#This Row],  Column1]]")=MIN(INDIRECT("Table1[#This Row]"))**